# whitespace in the format string (scanf)

Tags: c, input, whitespace, scanf, stdio

Consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=3, j=4;
    scanf("%d c %d",&i,&j);
    printf("%d %d",i,j);
    return 0;
}
```

It works if I give `2c3` or `2 c 3` or `2c 3` as input if I have to change the value of variables. What should I do if I want the user to enter the same pattern as I want means if `%dc%d` then only `2c3` is acceptable and not `2 c 3` and vice versa if it is `%d c %d`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Whitespace** in the format string matches 0 or more whitespace characters in the input.

So `"%d c %d"` expects number, then any amount of whitespace characters, then character `c`, then any amount of whitespace characters and another number at the end.

`"%dc%d"` expects number, `c`, number.

---

Also note, that if you use `*` in the format string, it suppresses assignment:
`%*c` = read 1 character, but don't assign it to any variable

So you can use `"%d%*c c%*c %d"` if you want to **force** user to enter: number, at least 1 character followed by any amount of whitespace characters, `c`, at least 1 character followed by any amount of whitespace characters again and number.

Comment: While correct, this doesn't actually answer the question as to how to proceed if you want to insist on whitespace or no whitespace.

Comment: This answer incorrectly implies that whitespace is not allowed before the integer.  `"%dc%d"` expects any amount of whitespace characters, number, `'c'`, any amount of whitespace characters, number.`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to accept `1c2` but not `1 c 2`, use the pattern without the space:

```
scanf("%dc%d", &x, &y);
```

If you want to accept `1c2` and `1 c 2` (and also `1 \t \t  c \t 2` etc), use the pattern with the space:

```
scanf("%d c %d", &x, &y);
```

If you want to accept `1 c 2` but not `1c2`, add a fake string containing whitespace:

```
scanf("%d%*[ \t]c%*[ \t]%d", &x, &y);
```

Here the format string `%[ \t]` would mean "read a string that contains any number of space and tab characters"; but using the additional `*`, it becomes "*expect* a string that contains any number of space and tab characters; then *discard it*"

Comment: The space before `"%d"` in `"%d c %d"` is irrelevant - same result as ``"%d c%d"``.  Whitespace will be acceptable even without that leading space.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would read the scanf result into different variables (i.e. not reuse `i` and `j`) as `"%d%s%d"`. Then check the string you got from the %s and if it matches your requirements, use the other variables to overwrite i and j.

Answer (score 0):

Force a string parsing first :

```
char a[100], b[100];
scanf("%99s c %99s", a, b);
```

Then use sscanf() to convert the strings to int.