# How do I read a string until a comma in C89?

Tags: c, c89, ansi-c

I am trying to read a CSV file in `c89` using `scanf`:

```
FOO,2,3
BAR,5,4
...
```

This is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char code[10];
    double a,b;

    while( scanf("%s,%lf,%lf", code, &a, &b)!=EOF ) {
        printf("> %s\n", code);
        printf("> %s,%lf,%lf\n", code, a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
$ ./a.out
A,2,3
> A,2,3
> A,2,3,0.000000,0.000000
B,5,4
> B,5,4
> B,5,4,0.000000,0.000000
$
```

This is the output I was expecting from the above code:

```
$ ./a.out
A,2,3
> A
> A,2.000000,3.000000
B,5,4
> B
> B,5.000000,4.000000
$
```

*Edit*

As per the comment provided I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char code[10];
    double a,b;

    while( scanf("%9[^,],%lf,%lf", code, &a, &b)!=EOF ) {
        printf("> %s\n", code);
        printf("> %s,%lf,%lf\n", code, a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I get:

```
$ cat > test.txt
A,2,3
B,4,5
C,5,6
$ cat test.txt | ./a.out 
> A
> A,2.000000,3.000000
> 
B
> 
B,4.000000,5.000000
> 
C
> 
C,5.000000,6.000000
> 

> 
,5.000000,6.000000
$
```

Apparently the first record is properly processed but not the subsequent ones.

Also I have the question about what the `9` does and if the whole `%9[^,]` is part of `c89`.

Comment: Did you try replacing your scanf reader's `%s` with `%9[^,]` ?

Comment: You probably want to test the return value of `scanf` against 3, in case you read some of the elements but not all.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have tried your solution, see the edit.

Comment: The example input you are showing and desired output don't match. But anyway, `scanf` is going to match the entire string to `%s` and have nothing left to scan for `%lf`.

Comment: That is the output I was expecting, I will edit the original question to reflect that more clearly.

Comment: Your "not the subsequent ones" looks like they have left-over whitespace from the end of the previous line.  You might try `" %9[^,]` that is, a space between the opening quote and the percent sign.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12835596/103167

Comment: And fyi, the `9` is to ensure your read operation doesn't blast pass the declared buffer size of `code` (10) and subsequently march into the land of undefined behavior.

Comment: To learn more about the format strings, please do some web research. The C standard can be found easily, in different versions, as some more resources. You should store the URLs and documents for future usage.

Comment: There are four things `scanf` will return in this case, `[EOF, 0, 1, 2, 3]`; UB if `[0, 1, 2]`, should at least replace `!= EOF` with `== 3`. @thebusybee the C90 standard is difficult to find.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround that is reaching each line into a buffer and replacing the commas by spaces first, then I apply the `%s`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char line[256];    
    char code[10];
    double a,b;

    while(scanf("%s", line) != EOF) {

        /* REPLACE ALL , BY SPACES TO SIMPLIFY SCANF USAGE */
        char *p = line;
        while(*p!='\0') {
            if(*p==',') {
                *p = ' ';
            }
            p++;
        }


        sscanf(line,"%s %lf %lf", code, &a, &b);
        printf("> %s\n", code);
        printf("> %s,%lf,%lf\n", code, a, b);               
    }    

    return 0;   

}
```

Not sure if it is the most elegant solution, but improves readability of the scanf part.