# After entering any value of p,r,n. I am getting SI=0 only

Tags: c

After entering any value of p,r,n. I am getting SI=0 only. Please help

```
int main()    
    {
        int p, n;
        float r, s;
        printf ("enter p,n,r \n");
        scanf("%d,%d,%f", &p,&n,&r);
        printf("value of s=%f",s=p*n*r/100);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Works fine for me (despite several unrelated problems with your code): https://godbolt.org/z/vMPPnhhax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commas in the `scanf` format string will be used to compare the input string.

Therefore, in your program, you have to enter `Number,Number,Number` such as `20,30,10`.

Remove the commas and replace them with spaces, which represent any kinds of whitespaces including spaces and newlines.

```
scanf("%d %d %f", &p,&n,&r);
```

Refer to [whitespace in the format string (scanf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835360/whitespace-in-the-format-string-scanf)

Comment: sir Thanks a lot_